# (How) Can I use Bigram Features with the OpenNLP Document Classifier

Tags: opennlp

(How) Can I use Bigram Features with the OpenNLP Document Classifier?

I have a collection of very short documents (titles, phrases, and sentences), and I would like to add bigram features, of the kind used in the tool LibShortText

http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libshorttext/

is this possible?

The documentation only explains how to do this using the Name Finder using the

BigramNameFeatureGenerator()

and not the Document Classifier

Answer (score 2):

I believe the trainer and classifier allow for custom featuregenerators in their methods, however they must be implemntation of FeatureGenerator, and BigramFeatureGenerator is not an impl of that. So I made a quick impl as an inner class below.. so Try this (untested) code when you get a chance

```
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;
    import opennlp.tools.doccat.DoccatModel;
    import opennlp.tools.doccat.DocumentCategorizerME;
    import opennlp.tools.doccat.DocumentSample;
    import opennlp.tools.doccat.DocumentSampleStream;
    import opennlp.tools.doccat.FeatureGenerator;
    import opennlp.tools.util.ObjectStream;
    import opennlp.tools.util.PlainTextByLineStream;



    public class DoccatUsingBigram {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStream dataIn = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        try {


          ObjectStream<String> lineStream =
                  new PlainTextByLineStream(dataIn, "UTF-8");
//here you can use it as part of building the model
          ObjectStream<DocumentSample> sampleStream = new DocumentSampleStream(lineStream);
          DoccatModel model = DocumentCategorizerME.train("en", sampleStream, 10, 100, new MyBigramFeatureGenerator());


          ///now you would use it like this

          DocumentCategorizerME classifier = new DocumentCategorizerME(model);
          String[] someData = "whatever you are trying to classify".split(" ");
          Collection<String> bigrams = new MyBigramFeatureGenerator().extractFeatures(someData);
          double[] categorize = classifier.categorize(bigrams.toArray(new String[bigrams.size()]));


        } catch (IOException e) {
          // Failed to read or parse training data, training failed
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }

      public static class MyBigramFeatureGenerator implements FeatureGenerator {

        @Override
        public Collection<String> extractFeatures(String[] text) {
          return generate(Arrays.asList(text), 2, "");
        }

        private  List<String> generate(List<String> input, int n, String separator) {

          List<String> outGrams = new ArrayList<String>();
          for (int i = 0; i < input.size() - (n - 2); i++) {
            String gram = "";
            if ((i + n) <= input.size()) {
              for (int x = i; x < (n + i); x++) {
                gram += input.get(x) + separator;
              }
              gram = gram.substring(0, gram.lastIndexOf(separator));
              outGrams.add(gram);
            }
          }
          return outGrams;
        }
      }
    }
```

hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can use NGramFeatureGenerator.java class in OpenNLP[1] for you use case.

[1] https://github.com/apache/opennlp

Thanks,
Madhawa